# Whats the difference between os.tmpDir & os.tmpdir?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was exploring the default OS npm in node their is a 2 properties with their same name one with lowercase (tmpdir) and other in camelcase (tmpDir). When i did a console log i see the same result.

So, Whats the difference between os.tmpDir & os.tmpdir in node? Any specific purpose?

Thanks
Dhiraj Gupta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same. [Check the source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/os.js#L58)

For reference, the code is:

```
exports.tmpDir = exports.tmpdir;
```

Btw: It's a method, not a property.

Comment: To be pedantic: `tmpDir` and `tmpdir` are properties of the exported object whose values are the same function.